# Comparing values in Array fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

Sometimes comparing two strings within arrays fails. Failing occurs occasionally only in looped `if`s. Example code below stands for implementing the problem.

```
searchTable.sort();
for(n=1;n<searchTable.length;n++){
  // alert(searchTable[n-1]!=searchTable[n]);
  if(searchTable[n-1]!=searchTable[n]){
    idx++;
    memTable[idx]=searchTable[n];
  }
}
```

Values in the `searchTable` are `strings` for sure, and all values are not similar either.

In loop, all values are set in memTable[idx], despite of the similar values in `[n-1]` and `[n]`. Activated `alert()` shows the right comparison result, but `if` passes all through. Looks like the comparison in `if` is done by reference, not by value. How is this possible? Is this a bug in the JavaScript interpreter or what?

Action can be corrected by adding `valueOf()`-methods to both members in comparison expression. I've crashed this failier whithin looped `if`s only. Sometimes it takes a long time to figure out why the code won't work.

Comment: 1) show a jsfiddle of the issue. 2) alert typeof searchTable[n] - perhaps it is an object and not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have concluded that the problem is related to the actual data in the arrays.  I suspect we can't help more specifically without seeing what that data is.

If putting `valueOf()` in front makes it work, then you can code a check for when the comparison with `valueOf()` is different than just straight `!=` and output the two values to the debug console or break into the debugger so you can inspect what values are causing the problem.  In other words, write code that catches the problem condition and allows you to inspect it.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. In the original code the values to `searchTable` was read from a text file by `FileSystemObject`, they certainly are strings. I'll try this in debugger, allthought I've to convert hta to htm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to remove double values from an Array.
Try using:

```
var tmpObj = {}, resultArr = [];
for(n=1;n<searchTable.length;n++){
  if (searchTable[n] in tmpObj){
    continue;
  }
  tmpObj[searchTable[n]] = true;
}
for (var l in tmpObj){
 resultArr.push(l);
}
```

Note: this will not differentiate between Numbers and Strings (so 1 equals '1')