# Why the index variable doesn't work for the javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, jquery-events

I have created a button(new_a_window), as it is pressed, it will append a button with an image in the html.

```
$( '#new_a_window').bind('click',function(){
    $('#story_pages').append('<div><button value="'+window_value+'" onclick="reload_to_canvas(this.value) "  ><img id= "w'+window_value+'" src="../pic/white_img.png" width="100px", height="100px"/> </button></div>');
    window_value= window_value+1;   
});
```

And when each new button is clicked, it will send its value to a function:

```
var write_back_to_canvas;
function reload_to_canvas(dataURLindex){    
    write_back_to_canvas = new Image(); //to new a object each time.        
    alert(dataURLindex);//check the dataURLindex content.
    current_page=dataURLindex; 
    write_back_to_canvas.src= img_dataURLs[dataURLindex];
    context.drawImage(write_back_to_canvas,0,0);
}
```

The problem is that: This won't work.(redraw the dataURL's image to the canvas) After many tests, I 
find the problem is not the drawImage method about the canvas.

> It's the problem of dataURLindex.

Since I have tried to replace the argument dataURLindex to 
integer numbers like:0, 1, 2 or 3...  And this work.
But as I use the `variable(dataURLindex)` as the index, it becomes invalid again.
What is strange is that as I `alert(img_dataURLs[dataURLindex])`
I can see the content... And `alert(dataURLindex)` display the correct number...

I really can't find another possible faults. Please any suggestions.

Comment: What if you use `write_back_to_canvas.onload = function() { ... }` instead? It does not directly relate to your symptomps, but it may be a coincidence that it sometimes works.

Comment: @pimvdb  no... It can't work.

Comment: Check the type of `dataURLindex`, maybe it's a string: `alert(typeof dataURLindex);`

Comment: @Teemu             It's a string, but in the several tests, I have tried to replace  write_back_to_canvas.src=  img_dataURLs[dataURLindex];  to  write_back_to_canvas.src=  img_dataURLs[parseInt(dataURLindex,10)]; And it still can't work.

Comment: Well what is `img_dataURLs`?  How/where is it defined?

Comment: write_back_to_canvas.src= img_dataURLs[dataURLindex.valueOf()]; also fails.

Comment: var img_dataURLs= new Array(); An array to store strings which created by canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
It's defined and declared in the start of the js file. 

var ...                                                              
var img_dataURLs= new Array(); 

window.addEventListener("load", ......

function xxx
function ooo
and other functions...

Comment: Only as I write write_back_to_canvas.src= img_dataURLs[0];
or write_back_to_canvas.src= img_dataURLs[1]; or another number
It can write an image on the canvas...

Comment: @pointy                 I've solved the issue. The problem is caused

Comment: I've solved the issue. The problem is caused
from the type error. The real type of the index variable is always string. But after I change it to dataURLindex.valueOf(), it works.
Although I still don't understand why the last trial failed, it works.  But I am not planning to answer my question. Please one of you: @pointy    can answer the question. You just need to give me more explanation why string-type index doesn't work
in an array, and why sometimes we use '+variable+' to get the content. I'll choose the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: @pimvdb          please see the description above.

Comment: @Teemu       Please see the description above.

Comment: It's weird you have to call `valueOf` yourself; what's between `[...]` is always converted to a string and I don't see what `valueOf` adds. But if it works then that's fine, I guess.

Comment: @Stallman Funny, my first question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056270/comparing-values-in-array-fails) here in SO was quite similar... Though I've accepted the answer, I still haven't a clue, why `valueOf()` is needed for some arrays.